# <ul> and <li> - Table with alternating row color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a table just like the one on the picture. I did this table with:

```js
<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example tr').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  if(href) {
   alert(href);
   return false;
   window.location = href;
  }
 });
});
```

```css
table#example {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#example tr:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
#example th {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#example th,
#example td {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
#example td:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Table</h2>
<div style="overflow:auto;height:150px;border: 2px solid grey;">
  <table id="example" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a>
      </td>
      <td>BBBBBBBBBBB</td>
      <td>CCCCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a>
      </td>
      <td>BBBBBBBBBBB</td>
      <td>CCCCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a>
      </td>
      <td>BBBBBBBBBBB</td>
      <td>CCCCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a>
      </td>
      <td>BBBBBBBBBBB</td>
      <td>CCCCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a>
      </td>
      <td>BBBBBBBBBBB</td>
      <td>CCCCCC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAAAA</a>
      </td>
      <td>BBBBBBBBBBB</td>
      <td>CCCCCC</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Table Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSM2A.png)

Question now is: How can I create a table like this only with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags?

I am trying without success. See how far I am:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example li').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  if(href) {
   alert(href);
   return false;
   window.location = href;
  }
 });
});
```

```css
table#example2 {
 border-collapse: collapse; 
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
#example2 li:hover {
 background-color: #ccc;
}
#example2 li{
 padding-top: 3px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left:-30px;
list-style-type: none;
}
#example2 li:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
#example2 ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:auto;height:150px;border: 2px solid grey;">
<ul id="example2" style="width:100%">
  <li>
    <ul>
     <li style="padding-left:10px"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">AAAAAA</a></li>
     <li>BBBBBB</li> 
     <li>CCCCCC</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I don't get it to look like the table with the table-tags. 
Could someone please help me by explaining how to achieve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can [use `display:table` and `table-row` and `table-cell`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table) to get table-like layouts.

Comment: this is the laziest thing ive ever seen you didn;t even try you just went thru the stylesheet and replaced `tr` with `li` ...your question was also extremely lazy.. you should go back and re-read it and fix the errors.

Comment: table#example2 ... really? how is that list-related?

Comment: remember to look at what you're asking. You're asking how you can make a *table*, using an *unordered list* element. The short answer here is of course "you don't, that doesn't make sense". Tables are for tabular data, lists are for sequences of list items. However, if what you want is an 100% width list with alternating color list element items, then the answer is pretty self-evident: just generate your list items, and use CSS to style even list items one color, and odd items another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/6/

add `display: inline` here:

```
#example li {
  display: inline;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: -30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Switch `li` with `ul` here:

```
ul:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

ul:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You are awsome, thank you so much. Did even think about chaning it to ul .